# Azure - App Registration - Edit existing entry of OAuth2Permissions doesn't work

Tags: json, azure, azure-active-directory

I can't seem to delete any existing entries from the `oauth2Permissions` array. Straight forward deleteting results in an error (be it via editor or file upload) and setting `isEnabled` to `false` doesn't update it at all.

1. Registered a new application via "App Registrations" menu

[image]

2. Edit manifest to add a second oauth2Permission

[image]

3. Go back to see the manifest file

[image]

Setting it to `false` again won't change anything. Change is accepted but manifest isn't updated.

Comment: Hi,Hans. I test this and came across same result as yours.  Even I updated a new json file to the Manifest, it still changed back to `ture`. It seems like we cannot change the status of oauth2permissions.

Comment: Great - thanks for the verification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a known bug in the portal.  We're working on a fix now, in the meantime you can use other mechanisms for editing your app (like PowerShell) to make the changes you need.

Edited to add: Forgot to say, the fix is currently in testing and should be rolling out soon.